# Netezza Error Data partition is full - When calling a Stored Procedure multiple times

Tags: sql, error-handling, netezza, partition

I call a procedure several times during a loop, when I run it 4 times there is no problem, but if I run it more than 4 times, I get the following error:

Data partition is full.

I am using distribution keys in my queries like suggested in the following website:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=35763b32-b40f-4178-8923-0b39edff7c7c

Here is the code that calls the function:

```
FOR i in  0 .. N
     LOOP
          CALL FUNCTION_X(last_day(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_VAR, i)));
     END LOOP;
```

I was wondering if there is a way for example that after each call can do some kind of memory flush or another thing in order to get rid of that error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it and now I tested it the function running it 18 times.
I only used a Commit after the call function. Here is the code:

```
FOR i in  0 .. N
    LOOP
         CALL FUNCTION_X(last_day(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_VAR, i)));
         COMMIT;   
    END LOOP;
```

Hope it helps to anybody that get this error.

Comment: Good to know. Whatever that function does underneath - it can’t be simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to execute that function (or is it really a stored procedure???) 4 times before it fills a disk, there are two options:

1) your system is 99.9% full on at least one dataslice all the time you need to free up some space (drop tables, repartition and/or ‘groom records all) on a lot of tables)
  2) a lot happens inside that function which leads to a dataslice running full. Try commenting out large sections of the code inside it to do a ‘binary search’ to locate the problem and then come back to us

Comment: Hi Lars, it is a stored procedure in which I create a lot of tables inside with many rows (millions). I already solved it by using "Commit"

Comment: By the way, it was a stored procedure, not a function, I already edit the question, thanks Lars!